# Opera fails fields validation on submit() with preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, validation, post, opera, preventdefault

I wanted to use HTML5 form validation along with ajax form sending. After the submit form should be replaced with some other content using prepend(), show() or something like that.

I was checking submit() and validate() functions and came up with this:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('sendmail.php', { name: $("#form-field-name").val(), email: $("#form-field-email").val(), message: $("#form-field-message").val()} );

   // now prepend the new "sucessfully sent" div
});
```

Looks like `e.preventDefault();` disables form validation in Opera, it works perfectly fine in Firefox/Chrome.

Any ideas? Is this jQuery/Opera bug, or maybe once again Opera is doing it right and the rest is not?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gw3My/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk in Opera. Not sure which browser is correct, but [this page](https://icewalker2g.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/html5-form-validation-quirks-opera-chrome-and-firefox/) explains the quirk and suggests a workaround using `this.checkValidity()`. Adapt it to your needs.

According to [this page](http://www.softexia.com/opera-12.html), this quirk will be fixed in Opera 12.

> CORE-35849 Submit event wrongly fired BEFORE client-side validation in HTML5 forms

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll stick to jQuery Tools Validator anyway, but can't wait for html5 validation support in all major browsers including IEs.